# How do I filter a list based on a certain value and unnest it?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to create a dataframe of all directory URLs for my Github repository. This is what I wrote:

```r
library(httr)
  req <- GET("https://api.github.com/repos/thedivtagguy/daily-data/git/trees/master")
```

In `urls`, I wish to only store the URLs of those items of `type: tree`. This is what `req` looks like:

```r
{
  "sha": "e5acaf1fd8973e010922ffc4366af68359de8456",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/thedivtagguy/daily-data/git/trees/e5acaf1fd8973e010922ffc4366af68359de8456",
  "tree": [
    {
      "path": ".gitignore",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "aaf221658979cc888d499702eea62beafa52d4e4",
      "size": 631,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/thedivtagguy/daily-data/git/blobs/aaf221658979cc888d499702eea62beafa52d4e4"
    },
    {
      "path": "README.md",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "2b0515e164c8a76d877324984f01e4bde6725410",
      "size": 1119,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/thedivtagguy/daily-data/git/blobs/2b0515e164c8a76d877324984f01e4bde6725410"
    },
    {
      "path": "_config.yml",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "2f7efbeab578c8042531ea7908ee8ffd7589fe46",
      "size": 27,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/thedivtagguy/daily-data/git/blobs/2f7efbeab578c8042531ea7908ee8ffd7589fe46"
    },
    {
      "path": "byrne_pebbles_8.png",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "95d9552636489a812d164e63776892c91c859785",
      "size": 10862,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/thedivtagguy/daily-data/git/blobs/95d9552636489a812d164e63776892c91c859785"
    },
    {
      "path": "dd01_kharifAndRabiCrops",
      "mode": "040000",
      "type": "tree",
      "sha": "b0863850cf04b73f76a8ed1f60558c6d340d142a",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/thedivtagguy/daily-data/git/trees/b0863850cf04b73f76a8ed1f60558c6d340d142a"
    }
```

This is what I have written:

```r
  reponse <- content(req)$tree
  urls <- response %>%
    map( ~ ., ~ filter(.x, type == "tree")) %>%
    unnest(url)
```

But this does not work, I am getting this error:

```r
Error in UseMethod("unnest") : 
  no applicable method for 'unnest' applied to an object of class "list"
```

How do I filter so that I can only store the URLs of items of type `tree`? I know how do to this in base R but I would prefer a tidy approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may loop over the 'response' nested `list`, and convert the named inner list to `tibble` by binding with `bind_cols` - if we use `map` to loop, it will return a `list` of `tibble`, by adding the suffix `_dfr`, it rbinds the `list`s of tibbles to a single tibble output.  Then, do the `filter`ing on the 'type' column

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dfr(response, bind_cols) %>% 
    filter(type == 'tree')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 6
  path                    mode   type  sha                                       size url                                   
  <chr>                   <chr>  <chr> <chr>                                    <int> <chr>                                 
1 dd01_kharifAndRabiCrops 040000 tree  b0863850cf04b73f76a8ed1f60558c6d340d142a    NA https://api.github.com/repos/thedivta…
2 dd02_commonSenseMedia   040000 tree  93461ea8897a3dcd026a88e62a284ba4a835a219    NA https://api.github.com/repos/thedivta…
3 dd03_cropYieldsD3       040000 tree  63b5de06defae6e8524e40d7942ba61ed2a599fc    NA https://api.github.com/repos/thedivta…
4 dd04_digitsPi           040000 tree  0f7e99e051a41fef6cde2706e6ded7538c3b6f8f    NA https://api.github.com/repos/thedivta…
5 dd05_indiaR             040000 tree  2bd552a7f9918602df043d54130c3d0b33d27294    NA https://api.github.com/repos/thedivta…
6 dd06_ttDrWho            040000 tree  7a0e0461228e0b39ba202032e09b46ba49e7eab6    NA https://api.github.com/repos/thedivta…
7 dd07_ggWaves            040000 tree  06def68fecdf576d45efa16ba6d98bba27edcc8f    NA https://api.github.com/repos/thedivta…
8 resources               040000 tree  ed4cb9ff46f19764292dea8e655dd4a500389dda    NA https://api.github.com/repos/thedivta…
```

Comment: Oh wow, so short and simple. Thank you, I will look into map_dfr and other purrr functions in more detail

Comment: @Aman thank you.  I added some explanation